# Getting Parse Error in React

Tags: javascript

```
    const Styles = () => {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius:2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation:1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10

  }
```

I am trying to do this styling in react.js. But the console shows parse error in for borderRadius:2, Error is as: Unexpected token , expected ;

Comment: Put attention in the brackets

Comment: Try to replace the border radius values, use strings instead,  and tell us what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are missing closing bracket for `Styles` object.

```
const Styles = () => ({
    containerStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius:2,
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation:1,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
});
```

Comment: Excuse me but I must have missed it here. But problem is not the bracket it is as stated in the question.

Comment: See updated answer. It's about brackets. When returning object literal, you have to wrap it in `()`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in my project this const Styles should have been an object instead of the function. Hence it was showing error and was asking for ; instead of ,.
Thanks

Comment: You are wrong. It was not complaining about `Styles` being a function, instead of object. See my answer, you forgot to wrap returned object in `()`